# Entity Framework: read data from generic table with unknown type column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am new to Entity Framework, and in my project I have to perform a generic query to retrieve the maximum value of a db column. Let's say that this is my main method:

```cs
long GetMaxValue(string tableName, string columnName)
{
    // code here
}
```

and the SQL equivalent is literally

```sql
SELECT MAX(<columnName>) FROM <tableName>
```

I have created a `GenericDbEntity` class which contains only a `NumericColumn` property representing this column, and in the implementation of `OnModelCreating` inside my `DbContext` I have this:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<GenericDbEntity>().ToTable(tableName).HasNoKey();
modelBuilder.Entity<GenericDbEntity>().Property(e => e.NumericColumn)
                                      .HasColumnName(columnName)
                                      .HasConversion(p => (?)p, (? p) => Convert.ToInt64(p));
```

The question marks inside `HasConversion` are because I don't actually know which is the db type of that column (I only know it's numeric), but I want to convert it to `long`, since that's the data type of `GenericDbEntity.NumericColumn`. I tried to replace the question marks with `object`, but it says:

> The property 'GenericDbEntity.NumericColumn' is of type 'object' which is not supported by the current database provider. Either change the property CLR type, or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

PS: I tried also to use `dynamic`, both in `HasConversion` and as data type of `NumericColumn`, but it didn't help.

Edit: The called compiled query is this one:

```cs
private static readonly Func<DatabaseContext, long> getMaxValue =
    EF.CompileQuery((DatabaseContext context) =>
                        context.GenericEntity
                               .Max(e => e.NumericColumn));
```

Comment: EF Core deals with entities, as in *business* or *application* entities, not tables, and there's no such thing as a "generic" table. `DbSet<T>` is already generic. It's job is to map entities to tables.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What's the purpose of that `GetMaxValue` method? Are you trying to use EF as if it was a SQL generator? It's not. Neither is it a data access libary, that's the job of ADO.NET. It's an Object-to-Relational *Mapper*. A DbSet<T> is already a generic repository. A DbContext is a multi-entity unit-of-work and repository for *specific* scenarios/use cases. You can already use the generic LINQ methods to retried the max value of any field: `salesContext.Products.Max(p=>p.Price);` or even `salesContext.Set<Product>().Max(p=>p.Price)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I edited the question adding the compiled query that is called. The purpose of `GetMaxValue` is exactly what I said in the question, that is, get the maximum value of a generic column, whose name is passed as argument. This method is called for generating new incremental IDs/counters before inserting data (not the best solution, it's temporary, and not my decision; I am just the person that has to implement it).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos when it was written for the first time, we were using a "raw" SQL query, but now we decided to move to entity framework, and this is one of the projects to be changed. I don't even know if it makes sense at this point

Comment: Don't do that then. You can't do that. EF isn't a SQL builder. It *uses* a SQL builder deep down. `we decided to move to entity framework`  you aren't doing that though, you're still trying to us ethe old raw SQL generator.

Comment: While it is possible, I want to know for which purpose it is needed before preparing answer. Because it looks for me like `nextId` generation.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv different services are handling SQL database items whose keys are composed by ID + version no, and each item can have different statuses during its lifetime. So yeah, basically this function is called to generate new id/version number (before inserting on db) for what I know, but I am not the developer of this versioning system so I can't provide more details.
PS: the reading is done only once, and then the number is incremented using Redis, and all the services access the same Redis db

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv what do you mean by "nextId generation"? Is there a EF functionality that can already handle this in a better way?

Comment: Which result type do you expect? cast everything to long?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv yep, long

Answer (score 0):

Added solution which generates LINQ query for particular table and column. For making it working you have to **REMOVE** `HasConversion` because properties with converters cannot be used in LINQ queries.

For example for call

```cs
var maxValue = context.GetMaxValue("Persons", "id");
```

Will be generated and executed the following query:

```cs
var maxValue = (long)context.Set<Person>().Max(e => e.Id);
```

And implementation

```cs
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static long GetMaxValue(this DbContext ctx, string tableName, string columnName)
    {
        var model = ctx.Model;

        var entityType = model.GetEntityTypes().FirstOrDefault(et => tableName.Equals(et.GetTableName(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

        if (entityType == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Entity for table '{tableName}' not found.");

        // GetColumnName() can be obsolete, it depends on EF Core version.
        var prop = entityType.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => columnName.Equals(p.GetColumnName(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

        if (prop == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Property for column '{tableName}'.'{columnName}' not found.");

        var entityParam = Expression.Parameter(entityType.ClrType, "e");
        var ctxParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DbContext), "ctx");

        // ctx.Set<entityType>()
        var setQuery = Expression.Call(ctxParam, nameof(DbContext.Set), new[] {entityType.ClrType});

        Expression propExpression;
        if (prop.PropertyInfo == null)
        {
            // 'prop' is Shadow property, so call via EF.Property(e, "name")
            propExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(EF), nameof(EF.Property), new[] { prop.ClrType },
                entityParam, Expression.Constant(prop.Name));
        }
        else
        {
            propExpression = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(entityParam, prop.PropertyInfo);
        }

        // e => e.Prop
        var propLambda = Expression.Lambda(propExpression, entityParam);

        // ctx.Set<entityType>().Max(e => e.Prop)
        Expression maxCall = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), nameof(Queryable.Max),
            new[] { entityType.ClrType, prop.ClrType }, 
            setQuery, propLambda);

        // cast if needed
        if (maxCall.Type != typeof(long))
            maxCall = Expression.Convert(maxCall, typeof(long));

        // ctx => ctx.Set<entityType>().Max(e => e.Prop)
        var maxLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<DbContext, long>>(maxCall, ctxParam);

        // probably we can cache such compiled retrieving function
        var func = maxLambda.Compile();

        return func(ctx);
    }
}
```